# Rvalue and Lvalue References

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function printInt like below.

```
void printInt(const int& a)
{
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

When I call like function using the following arguments like

```
int a=5;
printInt(a);
printInt(5);
```

It works perfectly.
But when I change the function definition to

```
void printInt(int& a)
{
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

This gives error to the call `printInt(5)`. Now my question is why `const int&` is both a lvalue and rvalue reference whereas `int&` is only a lvalue reference. As far as I know `int&&` is a rvalue reference. So how a single & can refer to an rvalue reference?

To summarize my problem:

1. Lvalue reference parameter

   ```
   void printInt(int& a)
   {
       cout<<a<<endl;
   }
   ```
2. Rvalue reference parameter

   ```
   void printInt(int&& a)
   {
       cout<<a<<endl;
   }
   ```
3. Both lvalue and rvalue. but how?

   ```
   void printInt(const int& a)
   {
       cout<<a<<endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: You could look at it as a mechanism to conserve const-correctness. Without declaring your reference as const, you are telling the compiler that you might be making changes to the parameter, but what is the meaning of modifying a temp rvalue object? The language forbids it.

Answer (score 9):

`const int&` is an lvalue reference. The thing is that the language specifies that it can bind to rvalues. `int&` is also an lvalue reference, but it cannot do that. That is why the first version works and the second doesn't.